# Why is my $p$-$T$ graph gradient increasing for decreasing radius when it should be decreasing in hard sphere collisions?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, ideal-gas, gas

Why is my $p$-$T$ gradient decreasing for increasing radius of spheres when it should be increasing?

I'm simulating some hard sphere collisions with
$Radius_{container}=10,$ and varying pressure and temperatures, I measured my pressure using average impulse/time $\cdot$circumference of the container, and $E_{k}=k_BT$.
[image]

There are 150 balls, the mass of each ball is the atomic mass of helium, the mass of the container is very large so it does not move. Calculated from 1000 collisions.

I used $p=\frac{Nk_BT}{V-Nb}$ to fit the straight lines, since $b$ increases with the radius of the constituent sphere, increasing the radius should increase the $gradient=\frac{Nk_B}{V-Nb}$. But it's the total opposite according to my graph? (the top line corresponds to Rb=0.01)

Comment: @Qmechanic, since you’re here, OP has been crossposting the same series of questions on Chemistry. I don’t know what you think, but I think they’re slightly better suited for Chemistry.

Comment: @orthocresol
 Please don't, I'm a physics undergraduate and Chemistry students rarely get asked to do hard sphere collisions simulation as thermodynamic investigation , I think (at least at where I study).

Comment: Crossposted to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/160299/7890

Comment: Your gradient seems to be inversely proportional to Rb and maybe Rb for the top orange line should be 0.005.

Comment: @ChernSimons Please note I have closed the question on chemistry.SE. You have an accepted answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradient seems to be inversely proportional to $Rb$ and maybe $Rb$ for the top orange line should be $0.005$.

> I measured my pressure using average impulse/time ⋅circumference of the container

Have you calculated the time for the balls to go across the container (correct) or the time using the radius of the ball and the speed?

Comment: The way I did my pressure calculation is as follows: Every time there is a collision with the container wall, I calculate the impulse, and after say 10 such collisions with the container, I sum up the impulse, divide it by the time elapsed between the first of such collisions and the 10th,  these 10 collisions give one pressure output. I repeat this for several times with the same sampling frequency of 10 collisions per sample. This gives several pressure data points. But I'm not sure about what correct this is?

Comment: @The gradient doing the exact thing as it is supposed to do. Rb for the top orange line is indeed 0.005, but this doesn't make sense because, 0.5 (largest radius) should have the largest gradient

Comment: @ Chern Simons Are you calculating the impulse from $2mv$ where $v$ is the velocity of the collision?  or doing a $Force \times time$?

Comment: I'm doing  $Force_{av, first \to  tenth}=m\frac{1}{\Delta t_{first \to \text{tenth collision with the wall}}}\sum_{n=1}^{10}\Delta v_n/ $

Comment: @ Chern Simons and when you calculate $\Delta t$ do you use the distance between the walls divided by velocity or have you used $R_b$ there by mistake?

Comment: No I don't think so. $\delta t_{first\to tenth}$ is actually measured rather than calculated. My system time evolves every time there is a collision, so each collision is associated with a time, I take the time when the tenth collision with the wall has taken place minus the time when the first collision  with wall has taken place to be my $\delta t$. Technically $\Delta t$ is different for each pressure output, where each pressure output is composed of 10 collisions with the wall.  In each run, I measure this for 1000 total collisions , which gives around 7-9 data points for pressure

Comment: @ Chern Simons Ok, have to stop soon, but the best guess is that in the computer code you have an $Rb$ instead of something else, maybe an $Rc$, (maybe search $Rb$), hope you find the problem, all the best.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Found my mistake. It was just exactly like you said! a $Rb$ was used in my circumference. Thanks so much again John.